# How can I get image url with product data in one json file?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $array = array();
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  foreach ($products as $_product) {
      $array[] = $_product->getData();
  }
  $gallery_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getMediaGalleryImages();
  $items = array();
  foreach ($gallery_images as $g_image) {
      $items[] = $g_image['url'];
  }

  $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array,$items);
  echo $jsonData;
  file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $array = array();
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
  foreach ($products as $_product) {
      $array[] = $_product->getData();
  }

  $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
  echo $jsonData;
  file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
  exit;
}
```

I got all data from this. If this wrong, please let me know. Thank you.